Script block not recognized
I have this script that have that error :
Register-WmiEvent: Cannot bind parameter 'Action'. Cannot convert the value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
Does somebody know why ? it seems taht for an unknown reason it is not recognized the script block

$logPath = "C:\USBScanLogs"
if (-not (Test-Path $logPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $logPath -ItemType Directory
}

function Start-USBScan {
    param (
        [string[]]$DriveLetters
    )
    
    foreach ($DriveLetter in $DriveLetters) {
        Write-Host "Scanning USB Drive: $DriveLetter"

        
        if (Get-Command -Name Start-MpScan -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
            # Start scanning the drive
            Start-MpScan -ScanType CustomScan -ScanPath "$DriveLetter\" -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "Scanning drive $DriveLetter with Windows Defender..."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Windows Defender not available. Please ensure it is installed."
        }

        # Log results
        $timeStamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        Add-Content -Path "$logPath\scan_log.txt" -Value "$timeStamp - Scanned drive $DriveLetter"
    }
}


function Get-RemovableDrives {
    # Get all drives except C:\
    $drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne 'C' -and $_.Used -ge 0 }
    return $drives.Name
}

# Monitor the event log for Event ID 6416 (USB device inserted)
Write-Host "Monitoring for Event ID 6416 (USB devices)..."
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.EventCode = '6416'" -SourceIdentifier 'USBDetection' -Action {
    # This is the ScriptBlock to be executed when the event is triggered
    
    # Get the event details
    $eventData = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.InsertionStrings
    $usbDetails = $eventData[0]

    Write-Host "USB device connected: $usbDetails"

    # Retrieve all available drives except C:\
    $drivesToScan = Get-RemovableDrives

    # Start scan on each drive
    Start-USBScan -DriveLetters $drivesToScan
}

Write-Host "USB Scan Monitor started. Waiting for a USB device to be inserted..."



Script code looks fine - can you tell us more about how you deploy and invoke this script?

As an aside: The CIM cmdlets (e.g., Get-CimInstance) superseded the WMI cmdlets (e.g., Get-WmiObject) in PowerShell v3 (released in September 2012). Therefore, the WMI cmdlets should be avoided, not least because PowerShell (Core) 7, where all future effort will go, doesn't even have them anymore. Note that WMI still underlies the CIM cmdlets, however. For more information, see this answer.

@MathiasR.Jessen i tried just to run it locally with vscode but it recognize the action part as System.String and not Script.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock

I can't see where there is perhaps an error with quotes not being closed, but I do have two remarks: [1] Your function Get-RemovableDrives is in fact returning all drives except the C drive. You could replace that with (Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne 'C' -and $_.DriveType -eq 'Removable'}).DriveLetter [2] Are you sure the -ScanPath parameter for Start-MpScan allows a bare driveletter like just F instead of F: (especially since you are combining it with a backslash..)
